# My vector is sorted and yet I'm getting a "sequence not ordered" error

Tags: c++

Are there situations in which `std::sort` fails?

I've got a `std::vector<KeyValPair<T>> queue` with which I do the following

```
std::sort(queue.begin(), queue.end());
std::pair<iterator, iterator> match =
    std::equal_range(queue.begin(), queue.end(), cost);
```

Exactly that. And then sometimes, not always, I get a "sequence not ordered" error.

The documentation describes [`sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) and [`equal_range`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal_range/) as using the same comparison functions, so I am confused how the vector could become unordered.

The `vector` type is the following class with custom comparison operators.

```
template<typename T>
class KeyValPair: public std::pair<double, T>
{
public:
    KeyValPair(double d, T t): std::pair<double, T>(d, t){};

    bool operator<(const KeyValPair<T>& rhs) const 
    { 
        return first < rhs.first;
    }

    bool operator==(const KeyValPair<T>& rhs) const 
    { 
        return second == rhs.second;
    }
};

template<typename T>
bool operator< (const KeyValPair<T>& lhs, const double& rhs) {return lhs.first < rhs;};
template<typename T>
bool operator< (const double& lhs, const KeyValPair<T>& rhs) {return lhs < rhs.first;};
```

Could the comparison function be failing somehow? What else can cause this error?

Comment: `std::sort` could fail if the sorting comparison does not implement a strict weak ordering.

Comment: @juanchopanza however according to OP it is not sorting that fails but the second function - equal_range.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev That is correct. It is equal_range which throws the error

Comment: Can you should a complete program and sample data for which the failure occurs?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Read the first sentence in the question.

Comment: What type is contained in the vector?

Comment: What's the element-type of `queue`? Does it have a custom comparator? Please add that.

Comment: @juanchopanza my interpretation of it is "are there cases when the sequence is not sorted after sort". I deduce this from the rest of the question

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Right, and if the sorting comparison does not imply a strict weak ordering, that could be one of the outcomes.

Comment: Definitely need the type and comparator for your queue.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev : after running `std::sort`, the data structure might not actually be sorted properly if the comparison function does not define a strict weak ordering. This would then prompt `std::equal_range` to complain. "fail" does not necessarily mean "generate an error" - it can just mean "fail to do what was expected".

Comment: Psychic debugging: `queue` is `std::vector<double>` and contains NaNs.

Comment: @2cents So, `std::vector<X>` where `X` is ordered by `double`, and the `double`s include a `NaN`.  `<` does not strict weak order `double`s in general.  You can detect `NaN` a few different ways.  Add `NaN` detectors.

Comment: You could try std::stable_sort(), which preserves the order of "equal" elements.

Comment: You don't want to inherit publicly from `std::pair`. It's not meant for that.

Comment: @chris as long as you're not doing anything that would slice the objects or delete via base pointer, there's nothing to keep you from using *anything* as a base type. That appears to be the case here. But I do question if deriving from `std::pair` really adds any value over a plain `struct`.

Comment: @2cents you're comparing doubles using `<`; I'd say that's close enough.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I would say even allowing the user to use it polymorphically is a bad thing. "Oh, it is a `std::pair`, so I should be able to put it in a polymorphic collection."

Comment: Your `operator<` and `operator==` are inconsistent, but that shouldn't matter, because the functions only use `operator<`. But if there were any NaNs, the sequence could indeed end up not being sorted by `sort` and the `sort` itself may not detect it produced inconsistent result.

Comment: @ecatmur It appears you are psychic. It took me a while to get the NaN test working, but there are NaN values present. My apologies for doubting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As first psychically detected by @ecatmur, your problem is you are using `<` on `double`s, and one or more of your `double`s is a `NaN`.

A safe `double` ordering follows:

```
struct safe_double_order {
  bool operator()(double lhs, double rhs) const {
    if ((lhs != lhs) || (rhs != rhs)) // NaN detector
      return (lhs!=lhs)>(rhs!=rhs); // order NaN less than everything, including -infinity
    return lhs < rhs;
  }
};
```

Next, we can write a key-sorter:

```
template<class K, class O=std::less<K>>
struct key_sorter {
  struct helper {
    K const& k;
    helper( K const& o ):k(o) {}
    template<typename V>
    helper( std::pair<K, V> const& o ):k(o.first) {}
    bool operator<( helper const& o ) const {
      return O{}( k, k.o );
    }
  };
  bool operator()( helper lhs, helper rhs ) const {
    return lhs < rhs;
  }
};
```

which passed a key-type and an optional ordering functor lets you search/sort `std::pair<Key,?>` with `Key` types directly.

```
std::vector< std::pair<double, X> > vec;
std::sort( vec.begin(), vec.end(), key_sorter<double, safe_double_order>{} );
auto match = std::equal_range( vec.begin(), vec.end(), value, key_sorter<double, safe_double_order>{} );
```

There are some C++11isms above, but the general design should be clear if you are using C++03.