# Sorting positive NaN's and negative NaN's in a vector

Tags: c++, nan, bubble-sort

I am attempting to create a program using a bubble sort in c++, i have to include positive and negative NaNs and sort them,I have got to the point where my program will sort negative to positive in ascending order including -0 and 0 but i am stuck on making it so that the NaNs are not mixed up.

How would i go about sorting these NaNs, possibly with the -Nans on the LHS of the integers and the NaNs on the RHS?

Comment: If you're sort is already working for real values what about `NaN` values is causing you a problem? What have you tried so far? Aren't you able to special case them in your comparison logic? (see [`std::isnan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan)).

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083716/my-vector-is-sorted-and-yet-im-getting-a-sequence-not-ordered-error

Comment: Why do you care about the sign bits of the NaNs?

Comment: @rici i am doing an assignment where i have to be able to enter positive and negative NaNs into a vector (which i have done) and then i have to sort them... so i cant have positive NaNs surounded by negative NaNs

Comment: @JamesAdkison I was not sure what to try because i cannot compare it to an integer to see if it is bigger or smaller in order to sort it, or am i wrong?

Comment: @RyanD96 Correct, you can't use the normal comparison operators.

Comment: @RyanD96: Odd sort of assignment IMHO. What is it intended to demonstrate? How do you produce a signed NaN? In any case, if you are allowed to look at the binary representation of the values, you can sort them "accurately" using a sign/magnitude integer comparison, which is pretty easy. Or perhaps you're not using floating point at all, in which case you need to clarify your question a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`isnan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) to detect NaN and [`signbit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit) to check its sign. You can use `signbit` to distinguish between positive and negative 0 too.

You will need to make a custom comparator to actually do sorting.

Comparator example:

```
bool double_order(double lhs, double rhs)
{
    if(std::isnan(lhs)) {
        if(std::signbit(lhs))  //Negative NaN is less than anything
            return not (std::isnan(rhs) && std::signbit(rhs)); //Except another -NaN
        else
            return false; //Positive NaN are never less than anything
    }
    if(std::isnan(rhs))
        if(std::signbit(rhs)) //Negative nans are tot larger than anything
            return false;
        else                 //Positive NaN are larger than anything
            return true;     //Except other +NaN, which is covered earlier
    if(lhs == 0.0 && rhs == 0.0)  //If both operands are 0, check for ±0
        return std::signbit(lhs) > std::signbit(rhs); //signbit of negative is true
    return lhs < rhs; //Otherwise do normal comparison (covers infinities)
}
```